# Problems with Sage installation on macos

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage, wordpress-bedrock

I'm running WP on my local MacOS using MAMP.
Have installed Bedrock and ran the WP installation, and all is running as expected - my website opening on `localhost:3000`.

The problem starts when I try to access the site after installed Sage. I am receiving `Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/` and I have no idea why I am getting this.
The moment I stop Sage, MAMP delivers the site. If I try to run Sage again, the error returns.

Just to make it clear, so I'll won't be doing some crazy mistake -

1. I have installed Bedrock.
2. Have installed Sage as a theme.
3. Mamp is pointing to Bedrock's folder, and website's port is configured inside Sage's `bug.config.js`
   Any idea what can I be missing?

npm: 9.8.1, node: v16.20.2/v18.17.1 (tried both versions).

Steps I did to understand whats going wrong:

- Have gave Full Disk Access to `/sbin/nfsd` ([reference](https://discourse.roots.io/t/need-help-on-fresh-install-of-trellis-bedrock-and-sage-locally-on-mac-catalina/17365)).
- Have disabled MacOS firewall

BTW- I was looking at the `package.json` file, and I have seen that Sage appears, inside the devDependencies, as version `6.12.12`. Its the latest version from the `git` repo. Is this means that I am using sage's version 6?